# No data is being returned when I use an inherited Django Rest Framework serializer? It just returns an empty dictionary

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer that is meant to act as a template for other ModelSerializers.

```
class CountryBasedModelSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, data, context):
        assert 'country' in self.Meta.fields

    class Meta:
        model = Country
        fields = ()
```

I want to use it with this, which is the actual serializer which will be called.

```
class CountryBasedProjectSerializer(CountryBasedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('id', 'country', 'name')
```

I want to use it with this inherited viewset:

```
class CountryBasedViewset(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = None
    serializer_class = CountryBasedModelSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(country_pk=self.request.data["country"])
```

And this is the actual viewset that will be called:

```
class CountryProjectBasedViewset(CountryBasedViewset):

    queryset = Project.objects.all()
```

Is there anything that I am clearly doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define the `serializer_class` for `CounteryProjectBasedViewSet` as below

```
class CountryProjectBasedViewset(CountryBasedViewset):

    queryset = Project.objects.all()
    serializer_class  = CountryBasedProjectSerializer
```